# How do I properly map entities where a primary key is composed of two foreign keys, one of which is composite itself?

Tags: java, jpa, orm, foreign-keys, composite-key

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to properly do ORM on a certain database design.

My schema consists of three tables: a user table, a review table, and a vote table. Users can publish reviews for albums, and they can also assign a positive or negative rating to any review. Albums are provided from an external API, so their table is missing from the schema, but their IDs are referenced.

A user primary key simply consists of their username. A review primary key is composed of the reviewer's username, which is a foreign key, and the reviewed album ID. Finally, a vote primary key is composed of the voter's username, again a foreign key, and the voted review's primary key, consisting, as said earlier, of the reviewer's username and the reviewed album ID.

A user can publish a review for each individual album, and also can assign a vote for each individual review.

This is the ER model representing the schema:

[image: er schema]

To map the entities IDs, I'm using the `@IdClass` annotation, but I'm not sure I'm headed in the right direction. I also tried using the `@EmbeddedId` annotation, but the result is the same.

This is what my entities classes look like so far:

```java
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

    @Id @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) @Column(name="signUpDate", nullable = false)
    private Date signUpDate;

    // empty constructor, getters, setters, equals and hashCode implementations

}
```

```java
@Entity @IdClass(ReviewId.class)
public class Review implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

    @Id @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "reviewerUsername", referencedColumnName = "username")
    private User reviewer;
    @Id @Column(name = "reviewedAlbumId")
    private Long reviewedAlbumId;
    @Column(name = "content", nullable = false, length = 2500)
    private String content;
    @Column(name = "rating", nullable = false)
    private Integer rating;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) @Column(name = "publicationDate", nullable = false)
    private Date publicationDate;

    // empty constructor, getters, setters, equals and hashCode implementations

}
```

```java
@Entity @IdClass(VoteId.class)
public class Vote implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

    @Id @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "voterUsername", referencedColumnName = "username")
    private User voter;
    @Id @ManyToOne @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "reviewerUsername", referencedColumnName = "reviewerUsername"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "reviewedAlbumId", referencedColumnName = "reviewedAlbumId")
    })
    private Review review;
    @Column(name = "vote") // @todo add attribute nullable = false
    private Boolean vote;

    // empty constructor, getters, setters, equals and hashCode implementations

}
```

These are my ID classes:

```java
public class ReviewId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private User reviewer;
    private Long reviewedAlbumId;

    // empty constructor, getters, setters, equals and hashCode implementations

}
```

```java
public static class VoteId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private User voter;
    private Review review;

    // empty constructor, getters, setters, equals and hashCode implementations

}
```

And here is the content of the MySQL script used to generate the schema:

```sql
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS albumReviewsDatabase;
CREATE SCHEMA albumReviewsDatabase;
USE albumReviewsDatabase;

CREATE TABLE user (
    username VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    email VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password CHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    signUpDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE review (
    reviewerUsername VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    reviewedAlbumId BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    content TEXT NOT NULL,
    rating SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    publicationDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    CHECK (rating >= 0 AND rating <= 10),
    PRIMARY KEY (reviewerUsername, reviewedAlbumId),
    FOREIGN KEY (reviewerUsername) REFERENCES user(username)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE vote (
    voterUsername VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    reviewerUsername VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    reviewedAlbumId BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    vote BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (voterUsername, reviewerUsername, reviewedAlbumId),
    FOREIGN KEY (voterUsername) REFERENCES user(username)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (reviewerUsername, reviewedAlbumId) REFERENCES review(reviewerUsername, reviewedAlbumId)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

I'm currently using OpenJPA as the persistence provider on a TomEE webprofile instance, and the used JPA version is 2.0.

Clearly I am misunderstating something about JPA's ORM, because when I deploy my application containing those entities I get the following exception:

```
<openjpa-2.4.2-r422266:1777108 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.util.MetaDataException: The id class specified by type "class application.model.Review" does not match the primary key fields of the class.  Make sure your identity class has the same primary keys as your persistent type, including pk field types. Mismatched property: "reviewer"
```

The exception is thrown because of the `Review` class mapping, and not the `Vote` class; however, I am sure that by solving the issue on the `Review` class, the same will reappear for `Vote`.

I'd prefer to get away with using the `@IdClass` annotation instead of `@EmbeddedId`, but whichever of the two I will end up using is not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These relationships are "derived identities"; so your ID classes should look like this (note the types of the foreign key fields differ from the types of their corresponding entity fields):

```java
public class ReviewId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String reviewer; // matches name of @Id attribute and type of User PK
    private Long reviewedAlbumId;

    // ...

}
```

```java
public static class VoteId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String voter; // matches name of @Id attribute and type of User PK
    private ReviewId review; // matches name of @Id attribute and type of Review PK

    // ...

}
```

Derived identities are discussed (with examples) in the [JPA 2.2 spec](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf) in section 2.4.1.

Also, as a side note, `@IdClass` is a bit Old School while `@EmbeddedId` is cleaner, eliminating the code duplicated across the entity and its key.